# TcpListener parser

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have a simple TcpListener and I want to parse the data it receives.  Here is what I have and it works:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
var buffer = new byte[10240];
var stream = client.GetStream();
var length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var incomingMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
```

results

```
Incoming message: POST /api/v1/myapi/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
ApiKey: dac38055e7914b1f8ca5de1683b58322
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 50da88e4-5c89-4368-a5eb-1574eb35b24a
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.1
Accept: */*
Host: MyDNS:13000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 590
Connection: keep-alive

AmazingDataFromBody
```

Is there anything that will parse this or do I have to write my own?

Comment: .Net provides the `HttpClient`, why not use that?  Or Web API?  It looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see, you want to handle an HTTP Request, so:

1. Instead of `TCPListener` use `HttpListener` to handle HTTP Request and Response. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2
2. Add the  Prefix to `HTTPLister` with your URI `http:localhost[:port]/api/v1/myapi/`, using the host and port.
3. `Start` the `HttpListener`.
4. Use `GetContext()` to get the `HttpListenerRequest` object.
5. With `HttpListenerRequest` you can get the Headers and body, check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2
6. Use `GetContext()` to get the `HttpListenerResponse` object.

Using the sample of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2 you can see:

```cs
    // This example requires the System and System.Net namespaces.
    public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
    {
        // 1
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        // 2
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http:/localhost:8080//api/v1/myapi/");

        // 3
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

        //4
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

        //5
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        //Building a response
        string responseString = "<HTML><BODY>My response</BODY></HTML>";
        //Take care of encoding
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

        //6
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        //Get the stream to wite the response body
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        // You must close the output stream.
        output.Close();
        listener.Stop();
    }
```

if you don't want to use `HttpListener` you can use these basic steps, using `TCPListener` and `TCPClient` but you must have knowledge about HTTP Protocol:

1. Read the Header, line by line.
2. Valid if there is Body, using the the `content-length` header.
3. Read the body, according information of the size of `content-length`.

In my case, i prefer use `HttpListener`, which allows handle several aspect of HTTP, like certified.

Comment: HttpListener does not work unless you use netsh and the application in admin-mode. TCPListener is by far more easy to implement.

Comment: Hi, Mario. You're right. With HttpListener you have to configure the port apart to use the Secure Layer (SSL, TSL, etc) and `netsh` is the tool to do that. As I wrote in my answer, and your comment, TCP Sockets are better but you must know HTTP protocol and how to perform an SSL handshake.